# Duda relacionada con las clases en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, objeto, clase

Estoy pasando un proyecto antiguo a programación orientada a objetos y tengo una duda respecto a ello. Yo he definido una clase aguja que tiene las siguientes variables:

```
class aguja():   

    def __init__(self):
        
       self.nombre=''
       self.pk=0
       self.vpaso=0
       self.zmot=0
       self.origen=''
```

Con esto quiero, desde otro script modificar la componente nombre con una pequeña ventana de tkinter. Lo explico a ver si puedo hacerlo de la manera más clara posible. Quiero realizar un vector de clases de agujas e ir cambiando la componente nombre de cada vector de agujas cada vez que pulse el botón. Para ello he creado ese script, pero cuando busco en la consola los valores de
vaguja[x].nombre, siendo x el numero que sea de la agujas que he añadido, siempre me sale el último valor que he añadido.

```
from tkinter import *
from elementos import aguja

raiz=Tk()

vaguja=[]
v=[]
str_prueba=StringVar()
b=0

def prueba(num):
    global vaguja, b, v

    vaguja.append(aguja)
    vaguja[b].nombre=num
    v.append(vaguja[b].nombre)
    str_prueba.set("")
    b=b+1
    print("vector v en el bucle:", v)

raiz.config(width=250,height=200)
label=Label(raiz,text="Prueba")
label.place(x=10,y=50)
entry=Entry(raiz,textvariable=str_prueba)
entry.place(x=100,y=50)
boton=Button(raiz, text="Siguiente",command=lambda:(prueba(entry.get())))
boton.place(x=100,y=100)

print("vector v fuera del bucle:", v)
    
raiz.mainloop()
```

Pongo un ejemplo, si añado números del 1 al 5, me sale lo siguiente en consola

```
vector v en el bucle: ['1']
vector v en el bucle: ['1', '2']
vector v en el bucle: ['1', '2', '3']
vector v en el bucle: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
vector v en el bucle: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

pero al buscar los valores con un print me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano y espero que haya quedado lo más claro posible.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Al copiar y pegar dice que  `holas` no está definido y que `prueba` no tiene atributo `set`. Por favor incluye el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el error

Comment: Disculpa por el error, intenté editar para que no hubiera cosas como holas y me quedé a medias, ahora ya está el código tal y como debe ser después de editarlo.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicación

El error se debe a que estás agregando siempre lo mismo a la lista: la clase aguja.

Cuando ejecutas esta linea:

```
vaguja[b].nombre=num
```

Lo que haces es crear o modificar el atributo `nombre` en la **clase** aguja.

Como todos los items de la lista se refieren a lo mismo, hacer:

```
print(vaguja[0].nombre, vaguja[1].nombre, ...)
```

Es lo mismo que hacer:

```
print(aguja.nombre, aguja.nombre, ...)
```

#### Solución

Probablemente lo que querías hacer era instanciar la clase aguja y luego agregar dicha instancia a la lista. Por lo que la solución sería simplemente agregar parentesis a la derecha de la clase aguja.

```
vaguja.append(aguja())
```

Cuando colocas parentesis a la derecha de una clase, habitualmente se devuelve una instancia de dicha clase.